# How to SUM() appropriate rows in MSSQL query for one column with INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql-server

I have a MSSQL query:

```
SELECT        Artikel.ArtikelID, Artikel.K_HerstellerName AS ManufacturerName, Artikel.K_HerstellerPN AS ManufacturerPN, Artikel.ArtikelNummer AS SupplierPN, Artikel.Bezeichnung + ' - ' + Artikel.LangText AS Description, 
                         Artikel.LetzterEK AS Price, Artikel.IstGesperrt AS Gesperrt, Lager.Verfuegbar AS Quantity, Lager.LagerPlatz AS LP
FROM            Artikel INNER JOIN
                         Lager ON Artikel.ArtikelID = Lager.ArtikelID
WHERE        (Artikel.K_HerstellerPN <> '') AND (Artikel.IstGesperrt = 'False') AND (Artikel.ArtikelNummer LIKE '%[0-9]-[0-9]%')
```

Here you can see how it looks like: https://ibb.co/fyOHv9

How to SUM() appropriate rows in MSSQL query for column "Quantity"?

In result all rows must be unique.

Comment: Why do you thinks this SQL- question belongs to Unix & Linux SE ?

Comment: I'm think the same as you, but i'm registered on the web only on this platform. ;) and i think, that most of admins can help me to solve this question.
SQL works also under *NIX

Comment: What is the criteria for "appropriate rows"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to group by all the columns that make each row unique, then use aggregate functions in your select, for example:

```
SELECT  

MIN(Artikel.ArtikelID ) ArtikelID,

MIN(Artikel.K_HerstellerName) ManufacturerName, 

SUM(Lager.Verfuegbar) Quantity

FROM Artikel 
INNER JOIN  Lager ON Artikel.ArtikelID = Lager.ArtikelID
WHERE (Artikel.K_HerstellerPN <> '') ...

GROUP BY
Artikel.ArtikelID, 

Artikel.K_HerstellerName,
```

...

Comment: "to group by all the columns that make each row unique, then use aggregate functions in your select" - nobody could explain this for me in this way: short and very exactly. Thank you for that.